# How to use Angular JS to update a page when an input paramater is changed on an event

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have a valid solution using webform (.aspx), C# and some Javascript.  I could use some help in learning using Angular JS.

I am looking for a way to re-write the solution to be a page in an Angular JS application. The example page has a Dropdownlist server control, when an item is selected, the div "axviewer" must be updated based the current value of a page member, "configJson".  configJson is a value returned from a static C# method taking the SelectedItem as an input.

---

```
  <html> <head>
    <title>ActiveX Viewer Sample Launch Page</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // configJson is updated and returned by a C# public static method
            // based on the selection in the list
            var ax = igc.be.client.activex.createInstance(<% =configJson %>);
            ax.render("axviewer");            
        });
    </script> </head> <body>    
    <form runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="prev" value='<' />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
            <asp:ListItem>288</asp:ListItem>      
            <asp:ListItem>483</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>488</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>501</asp:ListItem>                              
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
     <hr />
    <%--Display the Brava Viewer--%>    
    <div id="axviewer"></div>

    <div id="errorMesage" runat="server" visible="false">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ID="Description">Something is wrong!</asp:Label>
    </div> </body> </html>
```

---

Code behind:

> public partial class Viewer : System.Web.UI.Page
>       {
>           private static string instanceId;
>           public static string configJson = string.Empty;
>
> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         errorMesage.Visible = false;           
>         string docId = "273";
>         try
>         {
>             // return a json config string                
>             var selectedId = this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
>             instanceId = this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
>             configJson = ActiveXViewer.GetViewerConfigJson(instanceId, "admin:admin", docId);  
>
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             errorMesage.Visible = true;
>             Description.Text = ex.Message;
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

---

Answer (score 0):

as much i can understand from your question, it seems its not that complex what you want to do , but i would suggest you should first try it on your own.

I can help you out with some hints,

first have a custom directive in angular to mimic your stuff you are doing to manipulate the DIV based on the selected item

HINT http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_custom_directives.htm

then change the drop down selections using ng-select directive.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

rest if you are beginner, I would suggest to go with this first to make a clear picture in your mind that what n how angular works

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

I hope that Solves your problem